# Consumo de tempo em código cúbico

Tags: java, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Preciso calcular o consumo de tempo do seguinte algoritmo:

```
int somaSequencial(int v[],int n){
    int m = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = i; j < n; j++){
            int s = 0;
            for(int k = i; k <= j; k++){
                s+= v[k];
            }
            if(s > m){
                m = s;
            }
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Após nomear cada operação, de t1 a t15, cheguei a seguinte conclusão:

> F(n) = a + b(n) + c(n/2)(n+1) + d[ "Somatório de i=1 até n" (n/2)(n+1)]

Gostaria de saber se está correto, uma vez que se trata de um algoritmo cúbico.

Comment: Tem um método muito simples para avaliar o comportamento dessa função. Remova as variáveis `m` e `s`, declare no começo `passosLoop3 = 0` e `passosLoop2 = 0`. No lugar de fazer a soma em `s`, faça `passosLoop3++`. No lugar do `if`, faça `passosLoop2++`. Teste para alguns valores controlados de `n` e faça a interpolação polinomial que atenda a `passosLoop3` e `passosLoop2`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado voce ate pode meter os numeros [nesse site ai](http://www.dcode.fr/lagrange-interpolating-polynomial), que ele faz a isso por si. Pelos vistos isto é algo parecido a `x^3/6+x^2/2+x/3`

Comment: @BrunoCosta interessante o site, vou analisar com mais calma depois de sair do trabalho

Comment: Bruno Costa, como se usa esse site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu segui a ideia do @Jefferson Quesado. Voce pode obter a complexidade do seu algoritmo incrementado um contador. Básicamente voce só precisa saber o número total de iteracoes para cada valor de n.

```js
function somaSequencial(v, n){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(var j = i; j < n; j++){
            for(var k = i; k <= j; k++){
                total++;
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}

for(var i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
    console.log("(" + i + ", " + somaSequencial([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], i) + ")");
}
```

Como pode ver o output é o seguinte: `(0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 4) (3, 10) (4, 20) (5, 35) (6, 56) (7, 84)`

Agora pode fazer a `interpolação polinomial` para obter a formula. Eu usei [esse site](http://www.dcode.fr/lagrange-interpolating-polynomial). Voce só tem que pegar o output e meter lá na caixa de texto e obterá o seguinte resultado

```
f(x) = x^3 / 6 + x^2 / 2 + x / 3
```

Comment: Esta abordagem ignora o `if`. Se quiser contar com o `if` terá que ter outro contador. fazer o mesmo processo e fazer a soma das funcoes. Mas está claro que grau da funcao nao vai aumentar. Por isso a funcao pertence a `O(n^3)`